# c++ destructuring function return value

Tags: c++, std

Sorry if this question has been asked before. I am pretty newbie to this;

So, I have the following code;

```
template<typename K, typename V>

class test_class {
    std::map<K, V> my_map;

    void add_kv_to_std_map ( K const& key, V const& val ) {

        // And basically, i have the following syntax;
        auto [it, ins] = my_map.insert_or_assign(key, val);

        // Then perform other operations.

    }
}
```

The question is, in this syntax;

```
auto [it, ins] = my_map.insert_or_assign(key, val);
```

I don't really need `ins` variable. Is it possible to just retrieve `it` in there?

At first, I thought I could do something like this;

```
auto [it, ] = my_map.insert_or_assign(key, val);
```

But I spawn satan with that.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: afaik, at at the moment, no. There are some proposals being worked on for pattern matching that might help with this, but for now just take the return value, and use the `.first` part of it.

Comment: I see, i guess ill stick with what i have for now. Thanks @cigien

Comment: btw, if you get warnings about not using `ins`, you can use `[[maybe_unused]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't really need ins variable. Is it possible to just retrieve it in there?

No.

You can use a variable name that conveys the meaning that it is ignored. Personally, I prefer underscore (note that underscore is a reserved identifier in global namespace, so don't use it there).

You can use the `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute to signify to the compiler that the binding is intentionally unused:

```
[[maybe_unused]] auto [it, _] = ...
```

---

If you use `std::tie` instead of structured binding, then you can use `std::ignore` for this case:

```
std::map<K, V>::iterator it;
std::tie(it, std::ignore) = ...
```